# bash script to kill process on remote machines

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to kill process on remote machines via `ssh` but its not working

```
VAR=$(ssh ${HOSTS} ps -ef | grep $SERVICE | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9)
ssh ${HOSTS} ps ef < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Can you give us more input. no effect, or fo you have error?

You should try it without `> /dev/null 2> /dev/null` so that you have output

Comment: Are you trying to kill the pid on your local machine? Try 'xargs ssh ${HOSTS} kill -9'

Comment: i am trying kill remote machine java id.                    ps aux  | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9

Comment: i am trying kill remote machine java id.                    ps aux  | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9                                                    this will kill process when execute manually. but i want to execute from remote server

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your pipe process get execute on your local host rather than on the server.

A solution is to quote protect the command:

```
 VAR=$(ssh ${HOSTS} "ps -ef | grep $SERVICE | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill -9")
 ssh ${HOSTS} "ps ef" < /dev/null > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: After changes in script, though exception as kill: No such process
ERROR: garbage process ID "DCrawlerEntity.jar".
Usage:
  kill pid ...              Send SIGTERM to every process listed.
  kill signal pid ...       Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -s signal pid ...    Send a signal to every process listed.
  kill -l                   List all signal names.
  kill -L                   List all signal names in a nice table.
  kill -l signal            Convert between signal numbers and names.

Comment: spotted, coming from string interpolation. tell me if protecting the $2 in awk made it work

Comment: when i execute ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
on server this will working fine.but my requirement is to run from localhost

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked well for me to kill processes on remove server.
I'm able to kill  tail command running on remote server.

ssh -tty ${Host}" ps -efwww | grep tail |grep -v grep |cut -c 10-15|xargs kill -9  "